# vim; having problems when inserting/appending text

Tags: vim, text, insert, append, editor

I had a question regarding the gvim/vim text editor

I'am currently using gvim in ubuntu on a MAC notebook.

Every time i insert/append on gvim, it leaves a trail of "| | | |" in between the letter i write, the letter themselves or whenever i write a punctuation such as a comma, semicolon, etc.

(Example: " i|tream| |ead|hw |istr|am& in| dou|le h|) " but it should instead be showing this " istream& read_hw(istream& in, double hw) "  endofExample)

This issue disappears after i :q , or when i press enter for a newline, or when i click anywhere else on gvim.

I would like to mention that this problem is only isolated in gvim and nowhere else when i type on a different text editor, etc.

So the issue isn't a huge terrible problem but it has become quite bit of a nuisance when writing some text in gvim.

thank you.

Comment: That sounds like an annoying problem. If you don't get answer here, it might be worth deleting this question and asking on http://vi.stackexchange.com/ instead. Welcome to Stack Exchange!